# Android ListView : How to keep the ListView at the top when its content changes?

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursor

I have a view that contains a ListView which is bound to a cursor adapter. When The cursor content change I want to keep the ListView at the top then in my custom cursor adapter I added :

```
@Override
protected void onContentChanged() {
    // ...
    myListView.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

but this doesn't work. Then I read somewhere to queue this action like this :

```
myListView.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myListView.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
});
```

but this doesn't work either.

How can I keep the ListView at the top when its content changes?

EDIT:

Just for try, I added a button and called scrollTo() in its onClickListener and it didn't work! What am I missing ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Instead of **scrollTo**, try **setSelection(0)** to get to the top position of list view.

Comment: @jafar this should work. ListView's scrollTo applies to the ListView it self but listview isn't scrollable so the result is nothing. setSelection does the trick because it applies to the listview's adapter

Comment: Also note that `setSelection` needs to be called after `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Hi @weakwire, you said that srollTo doesn't work with ListView? Why is that so?

Comment: Hi @KarenAnne. It works. But not for the scrolling of the list view. It works for the scrolling of the view it self (that contains a list). So it is unusable.

Comment: You should also explain why `ScrollTo` is not working?

Answer (score 7):

i made functions that could be useful for others for listview scrolling, they work for me in every android version, emulator and device, here itemheight is the fixed height of view in the listview.

```
int itemheight=60;
public void scrollToY(int position)
{
    int item=(int)Math.floor(position/itemheight);
    int scroll=(int) ((item*itemheight)-position);
    this.setSelectionFromTop(item, scroll);// Important
}
public void scrollByY(int position)
{
    position+=getListScrollY();
    int item=(int)Math.floor(position/itemheight);
    int scroll=(int) ((item*itemheight)-position);
    this.setSelectionFromTop(item, scroll);// Important
}
public int getListScrollY()
{
    try{
    //int tempscroll=this.getFirstVisiblePosition()*itemheight;// Important
    View v=this.getChildAt(0);
    int tempscroll=(this.getFirstVisiblePosition()*itemheight)-v.getTop();// Important
    return tempscroll;
    }catch(Exception e){}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: above functions should be added to the class which inherits/extends ListView

Comment: Hardcoding height is not a good idea, Lists can handle mixed elements as well as multiline text with variable height. Also I wrote a lot of fancy `ListView`s neither needed extending the actual class. Consider at calling `View.measure(int,int)` for height of a specific item, after getting it from the adapter.

Comment: You are right hard coding height is not the correct approach, but commonly used listviews have fixed height elements, and scroll functions don't work on them, this is just a work around for scroll functionality. you can modify them according to you, "View.measure(int,int)" this can also be used, its up to you how you will modify them to suit your needs.

Comment: @Diljeet I improved your code for scrollToY which doesn't assume that each item is the same height. Instead of working out the item position from the height. Just plug the position into setPositionFromTop https://gist.github.com/Kisty/e2c3cd956a01a19661e8

Answer (score 6):

ListView's `scrollTo` applies to the `ListView` it self as a `View`

`setSelection(0)` does the trick because it applies to the listview's adapter

Comment: Also note that `setSelection` needs to be called after `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.