# How to preserve AutoCompleteTextView's DropDown state when gets back from launched Activity

Tags: android

Currently, when I

- Launch a new `Activity` by clicking on `AutoCompleteTextView`'s drop down
- Close the launched `Activity`
- `AutoCompleteTextView`'s drop down is hidden.

I would like to preserve `AutoCompleteTextView`'s drop-down state which includes

- Drop down should not be hidden when gets back from launched `Activity`
- Drop down's scroll position should be preserved.

I'm not exactly sure the reason why `AutoCompleteTextView`'s dropdown will be hidden when I back from launched `Activity`. Hence, I had tried 2 things

1. Change `windowSoftInputMode` of launched `Activity` from `stateAlwaysHidden` to `stateUnchanged`.
2. In `onActivityResult`, when the launched `Activity` is closed, perform `mSearchSrcTextView.showDropDown();` explicitly.

However, I am still facing the issue. The previous scroll position of `AutoCompleteTextView`'s dropdown is not preserved. It is reset back to top of the list.

Here's the screen-shot to better illustrate the problem I am facing.

---

[image]

(Current AutoCompleteTextView's dropdown is scrolled to **the end**. I click on the last item and launch a new `Activity`)

---

[image]

(New `Activity` is launched. Now, I click on the **BACK** soft key twice, to close the keyboard and then close the `Activity`)

---

[image]

(Due to the explicit call of `mSearchSrcTextView.showDropDown();` in `onActivityResult`, the drop down is shown again. However, its previous scrolled position is not being preserved. Start of list is being shown instead of end of list)

**I was wondering, is there any way to preserved the AutoCompleteTextView's DropDown state, when closing a previous launched `Activity`?**

Comment: you need to take a boolean variable which will be true if the dropdown is showing and false if not. then save that variable along with the dropdown list. and you can easily check if the variable is true then that means dropdown was visible you just make it visible. and for the specific position I believe you need to get the position of item where your dropdown list was in that way using that position you can scroll or go to that position easily ?

Comment: How do you able to get the scroll position of AutoComplete drop down, and programmatically change its scroll position?

Comment: I haven't tried it but just like we preserve the listview's scroll position I believe we can do something like that with autocomplete also.

Comment: How are you preventing the autocomplete view from changing its text when you choose an item from the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `AutoCompleteTextView`, it has a method called `dismissDropDown()`. I believe when back from newly launched activity, this function is being triggered. So we workaround this problem by extending `AutoCompleteTextView` & override it's `dismissDropDown()`.

We add a boolean flag `temporaryIgnoreDismissDropDown`, to indicate whether to temporarily ignore `dismissDropDown`.

```
public class MyAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {
    private boolean temporaryIgnoreDismissDropDown = false;

    .....

    @Override
    public void dismissDropDown() {
        if (this.temporaryIgnoreDismissDropDown) {
            this.temporaryIgnoreDismissDropDown = false;
            return;
        }

        super.dismissDropDown();
    }

    public void setTemporaryIgnoreDismissDropDown(boolean flag) {
        this.temporaryIgnoreDismissDropDown = flag;
    }
}
```

Before launching new Activity, we set `dismissDropDown` to true. After coming back from launched activity, `dismissDropDown` is called. The override method checks if `temporaryIgnoreDismissDropDown` is true, just set it to false & do nothing. So the real `dismissDropDown` is skipped.

```
// myAutoCompleteTextView is instance of MyAutoCompleteTextView
myAutoCompleteTextView.setTemporaryIgnoreDismissDropDown(true);

// launch new Activity
startActivity(....);
```

Hope this help, good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Diving into `dismissDropDown` solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

After an hour of coding, much trying and a lot of googling around, I've put together a solution that does just what you want. It uses reflection to access the ListView within the Dropdown menu and to access the dropdown state when you leave the activity.

The code for this is kinda long, so I'll walk you through all the parts. Firstly, I have some variables we will need:

```
boolean wasDropdownOpen;
int oldDropdownY;
Handler handler;
```

The handler will be neccessary for later, as we have to do a little trick in the `onResume()` method. Initialize it as usual in your `onCreate()` method:

```
handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
```

Now, let's get to the tricky part.

You need to call the following method before you start any activity. It can't be done in `onPause()` since the Dropdown menu is already closed when this method is called. In my test code I've overridden the `startActivity()` and `startActivityForResult()` method, and called it there, but you can do this however you like.

```
private void processBeforeStart() {
    ListPopupWindow window = getWindow(textView);
    if(window == null) return;
    wasDropdownOpen = window.isShowing();

    ListView lv = getListView(window);
    if(lv == null) return;

    View view = lv.getChildAt(0);
    oldDropdownY = -view.getTop() + lv.getFirstVisiblePosition() * view.getHeight();
}
```

This will save your dropdown ListView's state for later. Now, we will load it. This is the `onResume()` method we will need for this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (wasDropdownOpen)
        textView.showDropDown();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ListView lv = getListView(getWindow(textView));
            if (lv != null)
                scrollToY(lv, oldDropdownY);
        }
    }, 150);
}
```

First of all, let me explain this method. We saved the state if the dropdown was open, so we reopen the menu if it was. Simple. The next part is the scrolling. We need to do this in a `Handler` because the UI is not yet fully loaded when `onResume()` is called and therefore the ListView is still inaccessible.

The `scrollToY()` method you see there is a modified version of the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13409727/7702748), as Android's ListView does not have an inbuilt method to set the scroll position as precisely as we want it here.

The implementation of this method is as follows:

```
private void scrollToY(ListView lv, int position) {
    int itemHeight = lv.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
    int item = (int) Math.floor(position / itemHeight);
    int scroll = (item * itemHeight) - position;
    lv.setSelectionFromTop(item, scroll);// Important
}
```

Now, you've probably seen the `getWindow()` and `getListView()` methods I've used above. These are the reflection methods, which we have to use because Android does not expose a public API to access the ListView within the `ListPopupWindow` of the `AutoCompleteTextView`. Additionally, the `DropDownListView`, a subclass of `ListView` that is actually used within this object, is not visible to the oudside as well, so we have to use Reflection once again.

Here is the implementation of my two helper methods:

```
private ListView getListView(ListPopupWindow window) {
    for (Field field : window.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.getType().getName().equals("android.widget.DropDownListView")) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                return (ListView) field.get(window);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private ListPopupWindow getWindow(AutoCompleteTextView tv) {
    Class realClass = tv.getClass().getName().contains("support") ? tv.getClass().getSuperclass() : tv.getClass();
    for (Field field : realClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.getType().getName().equals(ListPopupWindow.class.getName())) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                return (ListPopupWindow) field.get(tv);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I've tested this on Android O (API level 26) and it works just as you described you want it to work.

I hope that the effort I put into this answer gets me a chance on the Bounty ;-)

Comment: Thanks. But the 1st answer help me tackle to root of problem, by preventing drop down list from closing.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng ok well then there goes 1 hour for nothing

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've already figured out how to show the drop-down on demand (via `showDropDown()`), so I'll only address how to restore the scroll position of the dropdown.

You can access the first visible position of the dropdown like this:

```
autocomplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        int firstVisiblePosition = parent.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        // save this value somehow
    }
});
```

Save the value of this `int` however you'd like (in memory, via `onSaveInstanceState()`, pass it through to the started activity so that it can pass it back via `onActivityResult()`, etc). Then, wherever you re-show the dropdown, do this:

```
autocomplete.showDropDown();
autocomplete.setListSelection(firstVisiblePosition);
```

The shortcoming of this technique is that it makes the item at `firstVisiblePosition` completely visible, so if it was halfway scrolled out of view, the list position won't be restored perfectly. Unfortunately, I don't believe there's any way to save/restore this partial-view offset.

Comment: My answer restores even the partial-view offset